# How to do XMLRPC with CherryPy

Tags: python, xml-rpc, cherrypy

Server (CherryPy 3.2.0):

```
import cherrypy

class XMLRPCServer(cherrypy._cptools.XMLRPCController):
    def index(self):
        return 'index'
    index.exposed = True

if __name__ =='__main__':
    cherrypy.config.update({
        'server.thread_pool': 1,
        'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.XMLRPCDispatcher,
        'tools.xmlrpc.on': True,
        'tools.xmlrpc.allow_none': 0, 
    })
    cherrypy.quickstart(XMLRPCServer())
```

Client (Python 2.7.1):

```
import xmlrpclib
svc = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://127.0.0.1:8080')
r = svc.index()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1575, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1312, in single_request
    response.msg,
xmlrpclib.ProtocolError: <ProtocolError for 127.0.0.1:8080/RPC2: 404 Not Found>
```

How do you enable xml-rpc in CherryPy, I've googled and read the docs but still stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's relavant quote from [`XMLRPCController`](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.3.0/refman/_cptools.html#cherrypy._cptools.XMLRPCController) documentation:

> The XMLRPCDispatcher strips any /RPC2 prefix; if you aren’t using /RPC2 in your URL’s,
>   you can safely skip turning on the XMLRPCDispatcher.

The following works fine. Also pay attention to separating global and application configuration, as you've mixed them up.

*sever.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import cherrypy


config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 8
  },
  '/' : {
    'tools.xmlrpc.allow_none' : True
  }
}


class Api(cherrypy._cptools.XMLRPCController):

  @cherrypy.expose
  def mul(self, a, b):
    return a * b


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(Api(), '/api', config)
```

*client.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import xmlrpclib


rpc = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8080/api')
print rpc.mul(2, 6)
```